# python / pip - whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip

this is yet another variant of the 'xyz.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform' question, but i couldn't find anything that fit my situation in the questions that were already posted.

specifically, the error i'm getting is

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: torch-1.4.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

however, this is definitely a python 2.7 platform and not python 3.  python -V gives `Python 2.7.5`.

fwiw, this is a centos shared hosting machine ; `uname -opr` gives `3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.26.7.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

the one difference in my case to other cases i've found is i'm required to install from a local file. i downloaded the file from pypi and tried to install with `pip install ~/src/torch-1.4.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`. the same is also true regarding `pip`, which isn't available on the machine ; i had to bootstrap pip using `get-pip.py` from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing). pip -V shows me the version is 20.0.2 (python 2.7).

the environment has `PYTHONUSERBASE` set to the root of the local install, and pip is in `$PYTHONUSERBASE/bin`.

i think this must be due to a problem with my configuration somewhere, but i don't know where. does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Run `pip debug --verbose`, this will give you a list of "_Compatible tags_", make sure one item in this list matches the _wheel_ file you downloaded, the `cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64` portion.

Comment: And what to do when the wheel I'd like to install does not appear in this list?

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip debug --verbose` in your terminal and you will get a list of Compatible tags. If one of them matches your filename, you should be good. Otherwise, find a tag closest to the file name and change the filename to fit it.